# Is there a way to get the correct hash of a zfs snapshot?

Tags: zfs

I'm sending a ZFS snapshot over the network. However, unlike most of the examples where there's a zfs recv on the other side, my server doesn't have zfs support and I'm just saving it as a huge file.

The issue is, that I want to zfs send using a cron job, but I periodically hibernate my computer. What I'm scared is that I'll start a backup, hibernate, time-out my ssh connection, and unfortunately when ssh (`zfs send POOL/vol@snap | ssh user@server "cat > /backup.zfs"` - this seems quite ugly and probably could be improved) times out, zfs still returns 0.

Is there a way to get a hash (md5, sha, crc, it doesn't matter) of what would be sent so that I can compare it afterwards to the result file, or would I have to send it twice, once to md5 and again to the server?

Comment: Do you know, is a `zfs send` deterministic?  (This is a question I have, and I have not yet found a clear answer.)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

You should be able to do something like this with the Bash shell:

```
zfs send [snip] | tee >(md5sum > checksum.log) | ssh [snip]
```

See the `Process Substitution` section of `man bash`.  (Thanks to Ole Tange for pointing out this simplification.)

Original answer:

There are a couple ways you could do what you want.

You could write a script (or a program in Python or the language of your choice) that would read from `stdin` while simultaneously (a) calculating the checksum and (b) piping the data to a subprocess (for example, to `ssh`).

Alternatively, you could probably also do something in Bash like:

```
zfs send [snip] | tee /proc/self/fd/4 4>(md5sum > checksum.log) | ssh [snip]
```

I have not tested the above, so I cannot guarantee it will work.  If you don't have `/proc/self/fd/N` on your system, then you may need to find (or write) some program other than `tee`.  See `man tee` and the `REDIRECTION` section of `man bash`, specifically, the `Redirecting Output` subsection.

Comment: This seems shorter and more intuitive: `zfs send [snip] | tee >(md5sum > checksum.log) | ssh [snip]`

Comment: Indeed it is simpler.  But how does it even work?  What is responsible for forking the stream?  It seems that `tee >` and `tee ... |` both redirect the same file descriptor.  I'm puzzled.

Comment: There is no `>` but a `>(...)`. They are not the same. Try: `echo >(true)`

Comment: Okay, so it is described in the `Process Substitution` section of `man bash`.